# Piecewise list comprehensions in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, piecewise

What is the easiest/most elegant way to do the following in python:

```
def piecewiseProperty(aList):
    result = []
    valueTrue = 50
    valueFalse = 10

    for x in aList:
        if hasProperty(x):
            result.append(valueTrue)
        else
            result.append(valueFalse)

    return result
```

where `hasProperty` is some function with boolean return value.

One shorter (but opaque, and possibly less efficient) R-like way to do it would be this

```
trueIndexSet = set([ ind for ind,x in enumerate(aList) if hasProperty(x) ])
falseIndexSet = set(range(0:len(aList)).difference(trueIndexSet)
vals = sorted( [ (ind,10) for ind in falseIndexSet ] + [ (ind,50) for ind in trueIndexSet ] )
[ x for ind,x in vals]
```

Another much tidier approach would use dictionary lookup:

```
[ {True:50, False:10}[hasProperty(x)] for x in aList ]
```

Is there some clever and readable one-liner or built in function for doing this? It would basically be an if...else list comprehension.

**Application of this question:**
Just in case it's of interest, I am using this to assign sizes to nodes in a network so that they are drawn differently. I want to draw nodes named with prefix "small_" size 10 and draw the other nodes size 50. NetworkX and pygraphviz can alter the sizes of the nodes by accepting a list of sizes, one for each node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) ([pep-308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)):

```
[50 if hasProperty(x) else 10 for x in alist]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
[50 if hasProperty(x) else 10 for x in aList]
```

?